# Div style is not functioning for input type text

Tags: css

I can't increase the font size nor i can make the border disappear. The style parameters don't get applied to the input type. I can style the other two divs mentioned in the code. Please point out what am I doing wrong?

```
<div style="font-size:20px;font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif">
   Contact us
</div>
<div style="font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;font-size:20px;border:none;display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;">
     <div class = "textbox" style="font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;font-size:90px;border:none;display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;">
        <input type = "text"    placeholder="First Name"  name = "email1" id="fname">
     </div>
     <div class = "textbox" style="">
        <input type = "text" placeholder="Last Name"  name = "email1" id="lname">
     </div>
</div>
<div style="font-size:25px;font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif">
    General Information
</div>
```

Comment: post your style code input.

Comment: There s no seperate style code in the css file . It s embedded with the html code as you can see

Answer (score 3):

> Try this apply your inline css directly on input i hope its work for you

```
<div style="font-size:20px;font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif">
    Contact us
  </div>
```

```
<div class = "textbox" style="font-family: 'Abel',sans-serif;font-size:90px;border:none;display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;">

  <input type = "text"  placeholder="First Name"  name = "email1" id="fname" style="font-size: 20px;border: none;">

</div>
<div class = "textbox" style="">

  <input type = "text"  placeholder="Last Name"  name = "email1" id="lname" style="font-size: 20px;border: none;">

</div>
```

General Information

Answer (score 2):

Directly apply css to input tag like this:

```
input[type=text] {
  //your css here
}
```

or if you are using inline css then

```
<input type = "text"  placeholder="First Name"  name = "email1" id="fname" style="font-size: 20px;">
```

because applying to div wont affect the input, it already have its own defined css.

Comment: Hey , thank you sooo much . Direct application worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to style your component you can style it with three types of CSS integration

1) Inline CSS
2) Internal CSS
3) External CSS

you can read on google about it.

For your question, you can do it instead

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:20px"/>
```

Or

```
<input type="text" class ="inputStyle"/>
 .inputStyle { font-size:20px }
```